# Reading a .bff file using Python

Tags: python, image-processing, binary

Is anyone familiar on how to successfully read a .bff file as an image array using Python? I believe this type of binary file has a header and is of mixed types.

Comment: Could you link a source that defines this format?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backup-file_Format

Comment: http://www.macfileopener.org/ext/bff

Comment: Maybe this also: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=files-backup-file

Comment: You might be more likely to get a response if you used Google Drive or Dropbox to share a representative `BFF` file along with a couple of images that are embedded in it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: do you really believe that you could reverse-engineer this format ? (Unless it is in reality a tar archive.)

Comment: Maybe you could run AIX under a virtual machine and decompress ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust It might be fun to have a try. And someone else might have some experience. Who knows?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I don’t have a file but can I have your email address to continue the topic?

Comment: I reverse engineered this format and implemented a quick and dirty unarchiver in Go: https://github.com/terorie/aix-bff-go

Comment: Hi KeksArmee, any chance you have a Python equivalent for this wrapper you created?

Comment: I assume the BFF file format you are asking for is not the same you need to. The Backup file format is a format used on IBM AIX operating system. It can store files like ZIP or  TAR file format. Not directly related to image processing. But here is a Python script I wrote to extract AIX BFF files: https://github.com/ponchofiesta/bffextract (based on KeksArmee Go code.